# How to write a write a constructor function for a Book and print all properties WITHOUT using CLASS function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6

I'm new to javascript. I want to write a constructor function for a Book with title, author and length properties by using the print method.I tried as following, I know it's not working. Please help!Thx!

Here's my attempting code:

```
function Book(title,author,page){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.page = page
    this.toString = toString
}

function toString(){
    return this.title + 'by' + this.author + ', is '+ this.page + ' long.'
}
print (){
    console.log(this.toString());
}

var mobyDick = new Book ( 'Hamlet' , 'William Shakespeare' , 82 );
Hamlet.print ();
```

Comment: What is `Hamlet` supposed to refer to? Why do you have `print` and `toSring`? `console.log(mobyDick.toString())` would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add the methods to the prototype so that methods are shared by all "instances" of `Book`.

```
function Book(title,author,page){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.page = page
}

Book.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.title + 'by' + this.author + ', is '+ this.page + ' long.'
}
Book.prototype.print = function(){
    console.log(this.toString());
}

var mobyDick = new Book ( 'Hamlet' , 'William Shakespeare' , 82 );

mobyDick.print()
```

If you're getting started, the best resource I can relate you to is You Don't Know JavaScript.
Here you have a [link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS)

Hopefully you find it useful. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Carlos! I'll check it out.